How to fix bubbles when drawing with canvas?
Good afternoon. I have recently started learning programming and would like to get a little help. When writing code to display bubbles using canvas, it turns out that all the bubbles merge into a single line. I can't figure out why this is happening. I will be grateful for any advice.
enter image description hereВот мой код:
const COLORS = ["255,108,80", "5,117,18", "29,39,57", "67,189,81"\];
const BUBBLE_DENSITY = 100;

function generateDecimalBetween(max, min) {
  return (Math.random() \* (max - min) + min).toFixed(2);
}
function generateColor(max, min) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() \* (max - min) + min);
}

class Bubble {
  constructor(canvas) {
  this.canvas = canvas;
  this.getCanvasSize();
  this.init();
}

getCanvasSize() {
    this.canvasWidth = this.canvas.clientWidth;
    this.canvasHeight = this.canvas.clientHeight;
}

init() {
    this.color = generateColor(COLORS.length, 0);;
    //  let min = 0;
    // let max = COLORS.length - 1;
    //Math.floor( Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
   
    this.size = generateDecimalBetween(3, 1);
    this.alpha = generateDecimalBetween(10, 5) / 10;
    this.translateX = generateDecimalBetween(this.canvasWidth, 0);
    this.translateY = generateDecimalBetween(this.canvasHeight, 0);
    this.velocity = generateDecimalBetween(40, 20);
    this.movementX = generateDecimalBetween(2, -2) / this.velocity;
    this.movementY = generateDecimalBetween(20, 1) / this.velocity;
  
}

move() {
    this.translateX = this.translateX - this.movementX;
    this.translateY = this.translateY - this.movementY;
    if (this.translateY < 0 || this.translateX < 0 || this.translateX > this.canvasWidth) {
        this.init();
        this.translateY = this.canvasHeight;
    }
}

}


function getRandom(max = 10, min = 0){
 return Math.floor(Math.random() \* (max - min) + min);
}

function getColor(){
let r = getRandom(256),
g = getRandom(256),
b = getRandom(256);
return `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
}

class canvasBackground{
constructor(id){
  this.canvas = document.getElementById(id);
  this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
  this.dpr = window.devicePixelRatio;
}

start(){
    this.canvasSize();
    this.generateBubbles();
    this.animate();
}


canvasSize(){
    this.canvas.width = this.canvas.offsetWidth * this.dpr;
    this.canvas.height = this.canvas.offsetHeight * this.dpr;
    this.ctx.scale(this.dpr, this.dpr);
}


generateBubbles(){
    this.bubblesList = []; // this для сохранения списка в контексте объекта
    for (let i = 0; i < BUBBLE_DENSITY; i++) {
        this.bubblesList.push(new Bubble(this.canvas));
    }
}

animate() {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvasWidth, this.canvasHeight); 

    this.bubblesList.forEach(bubble => {
        this.ctx.save();
        bubble.move();
        this.ctx.setTransform(this.dpr, 0, 0, this.dpr, 0, 0);
        this.ctx.translate(bubble.translateX, bubble.translateY);
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.ctx.arc(0, 0, bubble.size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        this.ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(${COLORS[bubble.color]},${bubble.alpha})`;
        this.ctx.fill();
        this.ctx.restore();
    });

    requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
}

}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =\> {
const CanvasBackground = new canvasBackground('orb-canvas'); 
CanvasBackground.start();
});


Welcome to SO! Could you please explain the reason for the backslashes (\\) in your code? Is that just because of copying or are they really inside your JS?

You're using the wrong properties in your call to clearRect(). It should be:
this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

Instead of:
this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvasWidth, this.canvasHeight);


Full snippet:


const COLORS = ["255,108,80", "5,117,18", "29,39,57", "67,189,81"];
const BUBBLE_DENSITY = 100;

function generateDecimalBetween(max, min) {
  return (Math.random() * (max - min) + min).toFixed(2);
}

function generateColor(max, min) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

class Bubble {
  constructor(canvas) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.getCanvasSize();
    this.init();
  }

  getCanvasSize() {
    this.canvasWidth = this.canvas.clientWidth;
    this.canvasHeight = this.canvas.clientHeight;
  }

  init() {
    this.color = generateColor(COLORS.length, 0);;
    this.size = generateDecimalBetween(3, 1);
    this.alpha = generateDecimalBetween(10, 5) / 10;
    this.translateX = generateDecimalBetween(this.canvasWidth, 0);
    this.translateY = generateDecimalBetween(this.canvasHeight, 0);
    this.velocity = generateDecimalBetween(40, 20);
    this.movementX = generateDecimalBetween(2, -2) / this.velocity;
    this.movementY = generateDecimalBetween(20, 1) / this.velocity;

  }

  move() {
    this.translateX = this.translateX - this.movementX;
    this.translateY = this.translateY - this.movementY;
    if (this.translateY < 0 || this.translateX < 0
          || this.translateX > this.canvasWidth) {
      this.init();
      this.translateY = this.canvasHeight;
    }
  }
}

function getRandom(max = 10, min = 0) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

function getColor() {
  let r = getRandom(256),
    g = getRandom(256),
    b = getRandom(256);
  return `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
}

class canvasBackground {
  constructor(id) {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById(id);
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.dpr = window.devicePixelRatio;
  }

  start() {
    this.canvasSize();
    this.generateBubbles();
    this.animate();
  }

  canvasSize() {
    this.canvas.width = this.canvas.offsetWidth * this.dpr;
    this.canvas.height = this.canvas.offsetHeight * this.dpr;
    this.ctx.scale(this.dpr, this.dpr);
  }

  generateBubbles() {
    this.bubblesList = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < BUBBLE_DENSITY; i++) {
      this.bubblesList.push(new Bubble(this.canvas));
    }
  }

  animate() {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

    this.bubblesList.forEach(bubble => {
      this.ctx.save();
      bubble.move();
      this.ctx.setTransform(this.dpr, 0, 0, this.dpr, 0, 0);
      this.ctx.translate(bubble.translateX, bubble.translateY);
      this.ctx.beginPath();
      this.ctx.arc(0, 0, bubble.size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      this.ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(${COLORS[bubble.color]},${bubble.alpha})`;
      this.ctx.fill();
      this.ctx.restore();
    });

    requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
  }

}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const CanvasBackground = new canvasBackground('orb-canvas');
  CanvasBackground.start();
});
<canvas id="orb-canvas">



